# How can I put a border around a text? from looking at the styles.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, border

this is my code in the styles.xml file;

```
<style name= "digado" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>

</style>

<style name="Transparencia" parent="ShowcaseView.Light">
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#000</item>
    <item name="sv_showcaseColor">#000</item>
    <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/digado</item>
</style>
```

I want to know where it says digado, if there is any way I could put like a border settings so that within the text that shows it has border around it.

Comment: You can use an xml Shape Drawable. Or a 9 patch.

Answer (score 1):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Define this drawable and then set it as background to your text view.

Comment: I am calling setContentTitle which is part of the Showcase view . its been done programatically so how can I go about doing it ?

Comment: what is your issue, I don't understand?